# TypeError: objective() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given, in scipy.optimize, minimize function

Tags: numpy, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I want to get the optimal value of alpha that balance the risk and the cost.(There are alpha_risk, alpha_cost, and risk_cost function given). Would set this problem as to minimize risk for a given level of cost.
In scipy.optimize, especially using "minimize" function, I keep getting the error: function() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given. This is the code that I wrote. Just erased the specific names.

```
`def risk(alpha_):
    if alpha_ + 1 < 0:
        return np.inf
    else:
    return 0.9 * math.sqrt(alpha_ + 1)
def cost(alpha_): 
    return  (1.1*alpha_ + 2)/(alpha_**2 - 0.6 * alpha_)
cost_constraint = 6.0

def objective(alpha_):
    if cost(alpha_) <= cost_constraint:
        return risk(alpha_)
    else:
        return np.inf 
alpha_constraint = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': alpha x: x[0] -1 }

alpha_initial_guess = 0.05
result = minimize(objective, alpha_initial_guess, alpha_constraint)
optimal_alpha = result.x[0]
optimal_alpha`
```

TypeError: objective() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

SO I thought this error holds because, during optimization, it doens't recognize the argument in objective function in correct shape. So I changed all the inputs into numpy array:
`def cost(alpha_): alpha_val = alpha_[0] return  (1.1*alpha_val + 2)/(alpha_val**2 - 0.6 * alpha_val)`
I thought this will solve the issue, since it is function of 1 variable thus 1D numpy array will have length 1 so alpha_[0] would extract the single value from this array.
However it still has the same problem with it.
**objective() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given**
As a 2nd approach, I assumed it takes 2 arguments, and modified the function so the other "unknown" argument that I have no clue about, wouldn't make difference in the the result.
`def cost(alpha_, h ): return  (1.1*alpha_ + 2)/(alpha_**2 - 0.6 * alpha_) + h - h`
Then it would output the error:
**unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'dict'**
So it seems the inputs structure would be something like 1, {'key';'value'} for this function. Not sure how I can perform minimize function properly.

Comment: Did you show us the full error, with traceback?

Comment: review the minimize docs..The third agument is `args`, not `constraunt`.  Be more explicit when calling `minimize`

Comment: it thinks you mean `, `minimize(...,...,args=alpha_constraint)`

Comment: Oh..I thought I could just skip the optional arguments. Now I understand why this had an error. Thanks